# How do you take a full webpage screenshot on a Windows computer?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, windows-7, screen, webpage-screenshot

Hi How I can take a full screenshot of webpage on a Windows computer using any browser?

Whenever I take screenshot with PrintScreen it take screenshot of only displaying page, but I want screenshot of full page in height. Is it possible we can take full screenshot including hidden eight?

Sorry for my bad English.

I have firefox and chrome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121870/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-save-web-page-as-image-redirect-issue

Comment: Do you want to do this manually or programmatically?

Comment: want to do it mannually, from my PC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some extensions such as `Fireshot`. The extension is available for both Firefox and Chrome.

Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/capture-webpage-screensho/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

**Less the extensions, the better. Without any extensions for chrome and firefox**

> Chrome - Go to chrome debug mode using inspect element or using
>   ctrl+shift+I or using F12. Then press `ctrl+shift+p`. And if you start typing `screenshot` you will see options and choose `Capture full page screenshot`.

And

> Firefox - shift-F2 or go to Tools > Web Developer > Developer Toolbar
>   to open a command line. And type `screenshot --fullpage` .  This one [Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158083/take-a-full-page-screenshot-with-firefox-on-the-command-line).

Comment: This is fantastic! It's a shame this isn't easier accessed and that it's not more well known.

Answer (score 1):

[Full Page Screen Capture board](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?hl=en) is most popular extension for doing it in Google chrome, it has simple and intuitive UI, very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Webpage Screenshot is popular extension for doing it in Google chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-screenshot/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki/details

Comment: Link not working. The requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific for browsers but there is a tool on windows called the snipping tool and it can take screenshots of anything.

Comment: he wants full page in height, not only displaying page