# Suppress the “are you sure you want to leave this page” popup in the Delphi TWebbrowser control

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser

I have an Delphi application that uses `TWebbrowser` component to automate navigation to another web application we have.

My problem is that sometimes IE shows the infamous 'Are you sure you want to leave this page' message and when this happens, my app can't navigate to another pages unless an user clicks on 'Leave this page' button. I can't edit the website code to remove this warning, unfortunately.

This message is plaguing my app for weeks, and I could not reach to a proper solution anymore. What I did is to keep a background process do manually send a keystroke when this window is show, but this is not a good solution because nobody can use the computer while my app is working.

I saw possible solution for C# in the topic below but I need a Delphi code instead.

[Supress the "are you sure you want to leave this page" popup in the .NET webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348692/supress-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-leave-this-page-popup-in-the-net-webbrow)

Any help is very, very appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: It's more likely you can do this with TEmbeddedWB, the improved version of the IShellDocView/InternetExplorer it has a lot more features than the TWebBrowser wrapper.

Comment: Why can't the user who is browsing click the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is shown by the underlying MSHTML engine if the web page handles [window.onbeforeunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event. Usually, it's there for a reason, to let the user know his/her input hasn't been saved or submitted yet. The prompt suppression script from [the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348692/supress-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-leave-this-page-popup-in-the-net-webbrow) doesn't work for cases when the page uses `addEventListener("beforeonload", handler)` or `attachEvent("onbeforeunload", handler)`. I don't think there's a reliable way of doing this, without resorting to low-level Windows hooks.

**[UPDATE]** The following script (look for "Inject this script") is a hack which aggressively suppresses the page's own handlers for `onbeforeunload` event, via `setInterval`. It should work in 99% of cases, but it still leaves a gap for the page to override `onbeforeonload` right before navigating away.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.attachEvent("onbeforeunload", function (ev) {
            window.event.returnValue = "onbeforeunload via window.attachEvent()";
        });

        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (ev) {
            window.event.returnValue = "onbeforeunload via window.addEventListener()";
        });

        window.onbeforeunload = function (ev) {
            window.event.returnValue = "onbeforeunload via window.onbeforeunload";
        };
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //
        // Inject this script
        //
        (function () {
            var onbeforeunloadHandler = function (ev) {
                if (ev) {
                    if (ev.stopPropagation)
                        ev.stopPropagation();
                    if (ev.stopImmediatePropagation)
                        ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    ev.returnValue = undefined;
                }
                window.event.returnValue = undefined;
            }

            var handler = null;
            var intervalHandler = function () {
                if (handler)
                    window.detachEvent("onbeforeunload", handler);

                // window.attachEvent works best
                handler = window.attachEvent("onbeforeunload", onbeforeunloadHandler);
                // handler = window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onbeforeunloadHandler);
                // handler = window.onload = onbeforeunloadHandler;
            };

            window.setInterval(intervalHandler, 500);
            intervalHandler();
        })();
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Go away</a>
</body>
</html>
```

To inject this script with Delphi, you'd probably need to resort to low-level `WebBrowser/MSHTML` COM interfaces, like `IWebBrowser2`, `IHTMLDocument2`, `IHTMLScriptElement`, in a very similar way it's done in the linked answer. With some more efforts, the same can also be done via late binding, using `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames` and `IDispatch::Invoke` only. If you're asking for exact Delphi code, I don't have one.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. I don't have the Delphi code to do it either, but what i did is a workaround better than send return keystrokes. When the document is loaded, i'm calling .navigate2 method with this : "javascript:window.onbeforeunload = function(){};window.focus();"

Comment: Although is not an 'elegant' solution, at least the infamous message does not plague me anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer you link to handles the browser's `Navigated` event. In it, it injects a script element into the page and into each frame on the page. That script assigns a new value to `window.alert` so that when other code on the page calls it, it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This code resets the event handler:

```
var
  WrkIHTMLWindow2: IHTMLWindow2;
  WrkIHTMLWindow2Disp: IHTMLWindow2Disp;
begin
  WrkIHTMLWindow2 := IHTMLDocument2Disp(WrkIWebBrowser2.Document).parentWindow;
  if WrkIHTMLWindow2.QueryInterface(IHTMLWindow2Disp, WrkIHTMLWindow2Disp) = S_OK then
    if not VarIsNull(WrkIHTMLWindow2Disp.onbeforeunload) then
      WrkIHTMLWindow2Disp.onbeforeunload := NULL;
end;
```