# Prevent "Are you sure you want to leave?" Javascript in Iframe from blocking top-level links

Tags: javascript, iframe

Currently some of my users visit another website through an iframe.

Often the site they visit through the iframe gives them an annoying *"are you sure you want to leave this site?"* message when someone clicks a link on my site to go to another page.

Now, I realise that I cannot control javascript on the other person's site due to cross-domain security.

But surely, because they are **clicking a link on my site**, I should be able to stop it triggering javascript on the iframe site? Or at least be able to move onto the next page without my users being upset and blaming my domain.

Here is what I need to disable at my top level:

```
window.onbeforeunload = "Are you sure you want to leave my anti social website?";
```

All I want is for visitors to be able to click a link on my site without being disturbed by the iframe.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348572/suppress-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-leave-this-page-popup-in-the-delphi-tweb

Comment: You can try to use sandbox for iFrame http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: @George-Cristian I'm looking now. There seems to be a script to reset the event handler? Is that javascript? How would I use it?

Comment: @jcubic that looks interesting - does it work on all browsers?

Comment: @George-Cristian that's a completely different situation; the browser in that case is being used as a component by another piece of software. This question is about how a *site* can control how an ordinary browser works.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=sandbox

Comment: @jcubic 90% coverage sounds pretty good. Would be nice if I could combine it with another approach to make it as close to 100% as possible though....

Comment: @jcubic I solved it......I solved something :DDD

Comment: Hello, I'm working on the same problem. What was your solution?