# WebBrowser Control failed to display a webpage

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

I am trying to navigate to following link in WebBroser Control, but its not displaying properly.
Actually it should display list of mails from a site. But its not working.

here is the link i am trying to show 
http://www.mailinator.com/inbox.jsp?to=8143081613

Here is the code i am using

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Show();
......
......

.......(button event handler)....

wb.Navigate(UrlTextBox.Text);
```

**Output from my program**
[image: Output from my program]

**Output from chrome**
[image]

Am i missing something?

Code is working for all other sites, but not working for mailinator.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider implementing [WebBrowser feature control](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18802626/1768303) to match the full IE browser behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, web browser control is using IE Rendering Engine see the limitations in [Webbrowser Control Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495944/webbrowser-control-limitations)